# Rails hosting with huge disk space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can u help me find rails hosting (preferably cheap) with unlimited or huge disk space?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "disk space"? DO you want a huge database or just to store loads of huge random files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want cheap rails hosting then your best option is [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com). They have plans starting from free.

They offer what many would consider "cheap" SQL database space for $15/month. You can get cheap NoSQL space as add-ons if that's your thing.

If you want to store random large files then you should use Heroku for hosting but hook your site up to [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) (which basically can be thought of as just a hard drive in the traditional sense).

Comment: thanks I will use heroku + amazon s3

Answer (score 1):

if you want bang for your buck and your needs are modest, go dreamhost. If that isnt good enough for what you need, go linode.